# The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) fixed

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a web browser application, but when I relaunch Visual Studio Community 2019, it shows me about 500 errors such as `The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

I tried reloading Visual Studio Community 2019 a few times, but still doesn't work either.

Some project infos:

- Target framework: .NET Framework 4.8
- NuGet Packages used: EasyTabs, CefSharp.WinForm

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using EasyTabs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before I post the question, I found out that you need to use .NET Framework 4.7.2 in order to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you're using easy tabs, I have the code for you. create new windows form project, in the project create another form and rename it AppContainer with the caps and everything, then open the app container with framework 4.7.2 then type in C# code

```
  namespace YOUR_PROGRAM_NAME_HERE
  {
      public partial class AppContainer : TitleBarTabs
      {
          public AppContainer()
          {
              InitializeComponent();

              AeroPeekEnabled = true;
              TabRenderer = new ChromeTabRenderer(this);
          }

          // Handle the method CreateTab that allows the user to create a new Tab
          // on your app when clicking
          public override TitleBarTab CreateTab()
          {
              return new TitleBarTab(this)
              {
                  // The content will be an instance of another Form
                  // In our example, we will create a new instance of the Form1
                  Content = new Form1
                  {
                   Text = "New Tab"
                  }
              };
          }

          // The rest of the events in your app here if you need to .....
      }
  }
```

also at the top of where it says using please type using EasyTabs and then type using CefSharp. basically every package code you use you need to refer to that package then add a subtitle for Browser. Next Open Form1.cs and type this Code.

```
    // 2. Important: Declare ParentTabs
    protected TitleBarTabs ParentTabs
    {
        get
        {
            return (ParentForm as TitleBarTabs);
        }
    }
```

type this where the namespace of your code is For example.

```
 namespace YOUR_PROGRAM_NAME_HERE
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       // 2. Important: Declare ParentTabs
       protected TitleBarTabs ParentTabs
       {
           get
           {
               return (ParentForm as TitleBarTabs);
           }
       }

       public object HTMLcodeec { get; }

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
```

now co into the program.cs file in your solution explorer and click on it one you do you need to type the following code

```
     namespace YOUR_PROGRAM_NAME_HERE
     {
       static class Program
       {
          /// <summary>
          /// The main entry point for the application.
          /// </summary>
          [STAThread]
          static void Main()
       {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

           AppContainer container = new AppContainer();

           // Add the initial Tab
           container.Tabs.Add(
               // Our First Tab created by default in the Application will have as 
                content the Form1
               new TitleBarTab(container)
               {
                   Content = new Form1
                   {
                       Text = "New Tab"
                   }
               }
           );

           // Set initial tab the first one
           container.SelectedTabIndex = 0;

           // Create tabs and start application
           TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new 
           TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();
           applicationContext.Start(container);
           Application.Run(applicationContext);
       }
   }
}
```

Now open Form1.cs and go to Form1. Load Event and at the top of it type

```
    ChromiumWebBrowser Browser;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        //Initialize
        CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true; // Enable Register JS Object, -- RegisterAsyncJsObject, RegisterJsObject allow
        settings.CachePath = "cache";
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1"); //Enable WebRTC4
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing", "1");

        BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings
        {
            FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
            UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
            WebSecurity = CefState.Enabled,
            WebGl = CefState.Enabled,
            BackgroundColor = (uint)CefState.Enabled,
        };

        Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(AddressText.Text);
        this.pContainer.Controls.Add(Browser);
        Browser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Browser.Load("https://ask.com/");
        this.AcceptButton = this.NavigateToURL;
        Browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
        Browser.TitleChanged += Browser_TitleChanged;
    }
```

before you don any of this please download cefsharp and easy tabs to your project

if you want to see my Browser project I build Go to https://cleverdamontoutube.wixsite.com/downloaddamonic and you can see what iv done
it is a .exe file you can download "if you need any more help subscrie to my youtube channel because ill be making a video on this topic shorrtly"